# Bul Kathos's Wedding Band Effect

Tags: diablo-iii

How does the Bul Kathos's Wedding Band effect, "You drain life from enemies around you", work when you are level 70?

Does it count as Life Steal, and thus is useless or does this get around that limitation?

http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/bulkathoss-wedding-band

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1. It returns 1% of YOUR MAX LIFE per second as long as 1 mob is around
>      you.
> 2. If more than 1 mob is around you you still only gain 1% of YOUR
>      MAX LIFE
> 3. It damages all mobs around you for 0.4% of MOB'S CURRENT
>      LIFE. Thus the damage it does to a mob gets smaller as a mob loses
>      life.
> 4. You cannot kill mobs with this effect alone, when their life
>      gets low enough it stops doing damage.
> 5. Range of it is extremely
>      short

Quote from http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/bulkathoss-wedding-band

Which makes me think it's life regen and not life steal. Others in this thread corroborate these numbers and statements.

Comment: wrong, it does not heal you whatsoever

Comment: Unless they changed it in the last month it does.

Comment: I have 500k hp, that ring definitely doesn't heal me for 5k lps while I'm standing next to an enemy.

Comment: @z' According to this [post](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12504790566) and some others, it does heal. I've read the effect might be activated by a hit of a monster.

Comment: What source do you have for this? You've got nothing here to corroborate your claims.

Comment: @Frank, see my comments to Z's answer.

Comment: @OrcJMR That's *your* source.  Which came after this answer was written.  Presumably he has something, somewhere, to back up his claims.

Comment: @Frank, oh, sorry, I thought you wanted to find out the truth. When I saw Richard's answer, I suppressed my urge to attack him for his attitude, quickly googled and found sources backing him up - what else?

Comment: @OrcJMR The onus is on the answerer to prove his claims.  If someone is saying something that is contradicted, it requires proof.  So far, we've got nothing.  I'm willing to take the word of someone more open (and more trusted, here), over someone who provides no proof, and seems to be attacking those that challenge him.

Comment: His source (copy/paste) is the second comment on this link: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/bulkathoss-wedding-band

Comment: After all of this discussion I was able to do a first hand test with this, and I am seeing both damage that diminishes as a monster starts to take damage, and a constant 1% life regen. Marking this as the accepted answer.